# Django Misapplying Migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-migrations

I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or it is a problem with one of the pieces I am using for the project.

Basically, I added a field to a model and am trying to make a migration.

Here is the model. The field is the `poster` one.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.TextField(default="")
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    videofile=models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='video/thumbnails', null=True, verbose_name="")
    tags = TaggableManager()

    actions = ['delete']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ": " + str(self.videofile)
    ...
```

That is the only thing that changed in the model. Let's make the migrations.

```
(app-web) selfishman@user-desktop:~/sites/app-web/app$ python manage.py makemigrations                                                                                                  
Migrations for 'video_uploader':
video_uploader/migrations/0007_video_poster.py
- Add field poster to video
```

So far, so good. Let's try to apply the migration.

```
(app-web) user@user-desktop:~/sites/app-web/app$ python manage.py migrate video_uploader                                                                                          
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: video_uploader
Running migrations:
Applying video_uploader.0002_video_creation_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
ils.py", line 85, in _execute                                                                         
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn: column "creation_date" of relation "video_uploader_video" already exists
```

There rest of the backtrace:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line                                                
    utility.execute()
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/__init__.py", line 375, in execute                                                                  
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv                                                                
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/base.py", line 353, in execute                                                                      
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/base.py", line 83, in wrapped                                                                       
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/managemen
    t/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle                                                           
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/
    executor.py", line 117, in migrate                                                                    
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/
    executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards                                                      
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/
    executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration                                                            
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/
    migration.py", line 124, in apply                                                                     
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/
    operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards                                                  
    field,
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ba
    se/schema.py", line 435, in add_field                                                                 
    self.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ba
    se/schema.py", line 133, in execute                                                                   
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
    ils.py", line 100, in execute                                                                         
    return super().execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
    ils.py", line 68, in execute                                                                          
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
    ils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers                                                           
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
    ils.py", line 85, in _execute                                                                         
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", 
    line 89, in __exit__                                                                                  
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
    File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/app-web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/ut
    ils.py", line 85, in _execute                                                                         
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "creation_date" of relation "video_uploader_video" already exists
```

This is the migration that was created:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

        dependencies = [
            ('video_uploader', '0006_video_description'),
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='video',
                name='poster',
                field=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='video/thumbnails', verbose_name=''),
            ),
        ]
```

Could someone tell me what is going on here? I am using Postgres 12. When I run tests, and an (SQLite) DB is created from scratch, there is no such error.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. We have seen quite a few inconsistencies when it comes to Django migrations and Postgres/Psycopg2. Not sure if something is up with the config or versions/dependencies.

Comment: Did you try to just run `python manage.py migrate` without specifying which migration to run? Django should be able to handle this for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It produces the same error, just in a different app.

Comment: can you revert your code up to that point and run the migrations just before this one? if so - after that add your code and make the migration. It seems like something is out of order there.

Comment: Could you explain? Revert the code to how the model was before I changed it?

Comment: Hopefully you work with some source-control (like git). I hope that you have some branch/tag/commit that works before you changed that specific model. If so - create new django installation, use this "point in time", run the migrate (to update all database structures), make sure everything work, and then make the changes in the model and run the migration again.

Comment: Yes, of course I have git. What variable would that help eliminate? Corrupt db table or cache? Django cache?

Comment: Mostly accidentally running a migration/db changes without reverting and then creating another migration and running it. It happens a lot when you move between branches/tags and run migrations, but not reverting them before moving to some other branch.

Comment: That is probably what happened. I was switching in and out of branches. What should I run when entering a new branch? `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: It's been some time since I last worked with django, so you need to check if the "migrate" also does rollbacks for you. If not - you will need to handle that manually (rollback before switching out of branch that has specific migrations).

Comment: @Dekel, thanks for your help. I went with a simpler method of just deleting the table in the DB and re-running the migrations. We are at a stage in the project, where that was affordable. However, it is a lesson for the future on how to switch properly from branch to branch. :)

Answer (score 1):

You created a new migration and it was named

```
0007_video_poster
```

However when you run the migrate it is running

```
0002_video_creation_date
```

And this is trying to create a new column named `creation_date` however that's already there.

You are getting inconsistent results because django thinks the previous migrations were not applied and therefore it is trying to apply them.

The easiest way would be to `flush` the database (make sure you first export any data you might need) using

```
python manage.py flush
```

This would reset the database and then you can run the migrations normally and it should work fine.

Otherwise if you want to execute the migration you just created i.e. `0007_video_poster`

You can run this

```py
python manage.py migrate video_uploader 0007_video_poster
```

Comment: I did try the last line even before I posted the question. It produces the same exact error. My reasoning is that somehow Django traverses up(down) the chain of dependencies until it hits `0002`, which makes it error. Note, that `0007` depends on `0006`, and so on. 
When it comes to the first part of your answer, is it expected that I do it every time I want to tweak a model? That is, it seems like a huge pain in the neck. :/

Comment: Try this out:  Delete all the files in your migrations folder (except init file) and then do makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: And no, you shouldn't have to.  I am also doing a project using Django and PostgreSQL... I encountered this problem once too. If nothing works, delete the table manually using psql command line and then follow the steps mentioned in the comment above.